# Using HTTP to get data in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am getting error after while using a property which is set using HTTP get service. Below is my code:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any){
    // this.queslist = this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name);
    this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name).then(mcquiz => this.queslist = mcquiz);
    console.log('hi');
    for(let ques of this.queslist)
    {
        this.max_score +=ques.score;
    }
}
```

I am getting error which reads like using Length on an undefined property. I assume it is because of for loop as service is using Promise to return data.

```
return this.http.get(this.quizquestionUrl)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json().data as mcquestion[])
           .catch(this.handleError);
```

Please suggest how to proceed. I want to set the maximum marks once questions are loaded and it should be done in ngOnChanges method.

Comment: Not sure why are you using ngOnChanges method. But try below code, that might resolve your problem.

Comment: @micronyks below code is working. Thanks. I am using ngOnChange as question list can change depending upon the quiz selected.

Comment: If it helped you, you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any){
    // this.queslist = this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name);
    this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name)
        .then(mcquiz => {

                        this.queslist = mcquiz;

                        console.log('hi');
                        for(let ques of this.queslist)
                        {
                            this.max_score +=ques.score;
                        }

         });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name).then(mcquiz => this.queslist = mcquiz);
    console.log('hi');
    for(let ques of this.queslist) //data has not arrieved yet
    {
        this.max_score +=ques.score;
    }
```

Move loop in then callback!

```
 this.quizdalservice.getQuizQuestions(this.name).then(mcquiz => {
   this.queslist = mcquiz
    for(let ques of this.queslist)//data has arrieved
    {
        this.max_score +=ques.score;
    }
});
 console.log('hi');
```